# Display message in checkout if a product from categoy X or Y is in the basket

Tags: conditional-statements, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm going to edit the shipping.tpl file of my Prestashop theme and what I need to do is to show a text if product from categoy X or Y is already in the basket.

Any ideas on how to get this conditional statement working in Prestashop?

Comment: .tpl seems to be a smarty template file so why not look in their documentation? https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl

Answer (score 0):

Use CartController or classes Cart to check if your product from a category is already in the cart.

CartController will use for display cart page so you can use the message controller error or warning, as you want

```
$this->warning[] = 'message';
$this->error[] = 'message error';
```

Cart classes will be used to check if the user try to add a product from category

Comment: Thanks for your reply Arnaud. Finally I had to use a module to solve my problem as I was in a hurry to finish the web.